# Can I use net.tcp bindings for protobuf-net WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, protobuf-net

Can I use net.tcp bindings for protobuf-net WCF?

Can I use ClientBase or I have to use ProtoClient?

Comment: net.tcp is for WCF<-->WCF communication so I'm 99% sure you can't

Comment: I'm glad it worked - if you have any other issues/feedback feel free to drop me a line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are already using TCP bindings for your WCF, then I would *imagine* that you can use protobuf-net; quite simply, I haven't tried this combination, but since the transport and serializer are separate I can't think of a reason why not.

I will have to try it, perhaps using the new endpoint stuff... I have a test rig, so I'll try reconfiguring the transport - see if it works. It is largely a case of applying the info [here](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/11/controlling-wcf-protobuf-net-at.html).

Comment: The problem was inherited classes and being a first time user asked it. It works like charm. No issues.

Comment: Is there any issue in supporting IList<T> by creating instance of List<T> and returning it.

Comment: It should work fine - are you seeing an issue? Line 60 in PropertyList.cs handles this, defaulting to `List<T>` if you use `IList<T>`...